# Store the most recent N MBs of a stream?

Tags: osx, wget, curl, fifo, streaming

I currently use wget or curl to download a continuous AAC-stream. I would like to limit what's stored on disk to the most recent N MB. In other words, some kind of size limited FIFO-buffer (I guess?). Any ideas how to accomplish this? This is OS X/BSD.

The purpose is to be able to stop the stream when something interesting has happened and then extract the last few minutes from it to a permanent storage.

Update: an alternative solution would be to interrupt every N MB and start a new local file and rotate out the previous file (that is, rename it with a sequence number, time stamp or similar). However, if doing this there need to be a substantial overlap between the files.

Comment: I would think in terms of a _circular buffer_ <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer>.  That would keep everything in memory, constantly over-writing to the capacity of the memory allocated. When you saw something interesting (how?), the buffer could be written to a file if that's where you would do some processing.  The upshot is that the slow disk is never really touched until it would be needed. Somewhat blue-skying here, but circular buffers were used extensively in CD 6600 OSs, which I used for a number of years.

Comment: How? I listen to the stream. Thanks for your suggestion, any ideas how to implement it?

Comment: Let's call this chunk of software cb. One would need to be able to interrupt the wget -> cb connection, so cb would need to be able to process a signal from the keyboard, cb then dumps the buffer to the disk, and you then use whatever tools to look at the disk file. The circular buffer is managed by 4 pointers: First, Limit, In, Out. Two processes can run simultaneously. If you do c++, the Boost libraries have a module <https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.circularbuffer> , if you do perl, there is some advice at <http://www.perlmonks.org?node_id=894330 >

Comment: Boost: <https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.circularbuffer

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple python script that may help. It just reads from stdin and writes to stdout, but keeps the last N bytes in memory. If you interrupt it with control-C (SIGINT) it dumps the memory into file `/tmp/sample001` and continues.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# circular buffer in memory without recopy using bytearray
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401875/119298
import sys, os

def copy():
    def dump(fd,v):
        fd.write(v)

    space = 10000000
    buffer = bytearray(space) # all zero bytes
    view = memoryview(buffer)
    head = 0; wrapped = False
    sys.stdin = os.fdopen(sys.stdin.fileno(), 'rb', 0)
    sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'wb', 0)
    fileno = 1
    while True:
        try:
            nbytes = sys.stdin.readinto(view[head:])
            if nbytes==0: 
                break # eof
            sys.stdout.write(view[head:head+nbytes].tobytes())
            head += nbytes
            if head>=space:
                head = 0; wrapped = True
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            filename = "/tmp/sample%03d" % fileno
            fileno += 1
            with open(filename,"wb") as fd:
                if wrapped:
                    dump(fd, view[head:])
                if head:
                    dump(fd, view[0:head])

copy()
```

If you don't have python3 it will need a few changes for python 2.7.
You might need to worry about how to preserve a legal AAC framing format, but perhaps if you try first you may find whatever you are using manages to self-sync from arbitrary offset data.